# CSS - layout of icons change from horizontal to vertical with screen size changes

Tags: html, css, layout

I have an issue when changing screen size (to different device or viewport) with some icons.

When the screen size drops 960 and below the icons change from horizontal orientation to vertical. I have break points in my css for @ media but nothing changes at 960 for the socialIcons or related divs above.

Icons are svg.

**Correct layout**

[image]

**Broken layout**
[image]

**Code Snippet**

```
#social_block {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 5rem;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#socialDisplay {
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
}
.socialIcons {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline;
}


<div id="social_block">

<div id="socialDisplay">CONNECT WITH US</div>


<div class="socialIcons">
<img class="link_item" id="FB" src="/xxx" rel="https://www.facebook.com/xxx/" data-method="open"> 
<img class="link_item" id="IG" src="/xxx" rel="https://www.instagram.com/xxx/" data-method="open"> 
<img class="link_item" id="LI" src="/xxx" rel="https://www.linkedin.com/company/xxx" data-method="open">
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Hello. When I copy your code to snippet as is, your icons always horizontal with any display size. How to repeat your problem?

Comment: Thanks for your help - I think some code below in the footer must have thrown it out. It is working now.

Answer (score 0):

I would add this to the social icons CSS

```css
#social_block {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#socialDisplay {
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}

.socialIcons {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<div id="social_block">

  <div id="socialDisplay">CONNECT WITH US</div>


  <div class="socialIcons">
    <img class="link_item" id="FB" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtPNz.png" rel="https://www.facebook.com/xxx/" data-method="open">
    <img class="link_item" id="IG" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtPNz.png" rel="https://www.instagram.com/xxx/" data-method="open">
    <img class="link_item" id="LI" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtPNz.png" rel="https://www.linkedin.com/company/xxx" data-method="open">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I thought `flex-direction` works with only `display: flex`. Could you back up your solution with a demo working snippet?

Comment: Sorry i'm new to the website so not sure how to make a snippet but w3schools has a nice breakdown of the flex-direction property heres a link [link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex-direction.asp)

Comment: There is an icon which has <> symbol on it. You can create a snippet using that.

Comment: sorry mate i tried to add snippet for you but dont think it worked? i added random images aswell just to show it working. If you try this code it should work i tested it on this website [link](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_default)

Comment: I've changed your code to a snippet. Your new code has `display: flex` which overrides `display: inline`. So my first question is not valid anymore.

Comment: Thanks for your help - I think some code below in the footer must have thrown it out. It is working now.